# Python dll function are not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, dllimport

I have wrote code as below to communicate with a dll.i have registered this dll.

```
from ctypes import cdll
# give location of dll
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\zkemkeeper.dll")
ip = "172.16.16.70"
port = "4370"
mydll.Connect_Net(ip,port)
```

I get the following error whenevr i execute it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\fetch.py", line 6, in <module>
    mydll.Connect_Net(ip,port)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'Connect_Net' not found
```

Also i m able to communicate with this dll and access its function using PHP.Can anyone let me know what can be the issue and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Python snippet:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
zk = Dispatch("zkemkeeper.ZKEM")
ip = "172.16.16.70"
port = "4370"
zk.Connect_Net(IP_address, port)
```

Comment: You should explain why this addresses the question.

Comment: He wants to connect to ZK terminal using SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: function 'Connect_Net' not found
```

This means that the DLL does not export a function named `'Connect_Net'`. Perhaps you got the name wrong, or the DLL failed to export the function somehow.

Some other comments:

- Using the backslash escape character is running the gauntlet. Escape the backslash, use a raw string literal, or use `os.path.join`.
- Don't modify the system directories. You should put your DLL elsewhere.

Comment: if this function does not exist in DLL than how php is able to communicate with it and access connect_net function,Also it is no me who is copying dll in system directories its our hardware (biometric) machine provider who copies dll to system directory.

Comment: `Connect_Net` and `connect_net` are different names. With respect there is no explanation other than what appears in my answer.